# how I fit this result within the div?

Tags: css, html

```
$smweb = explode(",",$smlar); $i = 0;
        foreach ($smweb as $webnm){ if ($i++ == 6)
    break; print "<a href='/".$webnm."'>".ucfirst($webnm)."</a>";
```

the above will result

```
<a href="/google.com">google.com</a>
<a href="/twitter.com">twitter.com</a>
<a href="/facebook.com">facebook.com</a>
<a href="/myspace.com">myspace.com</a>
<a href="/mixx.com">mixx.com</a>
<a href="/digg.com">digg.com</a>
```

etc.

The problem is it wont fit in the div id called "smweb" it goes outside and not break within the div limit. the div width is 500px. how can I fit the same within the div??

Comment: do you use float for your div? is your DIV really 500px, test it with firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space after the `</a>` - then it will wrap normally. Like so:

```
$smweb = explode(",",$smlar); 
$i = 0;
foreach ($smweb as $webnm) { 
    if ($i++ == 6) {
        break; 
    }
    print "<a href='/".$webnm."'>".ucfirst($webnm)."</a> ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminate your lines.

Use

```
print "<a href='/".$webnm."'>".ucfirst($webnm)."</a><br/>";
```